# CMake: How to specify target platform?

Tags: c++, cmake

How to specify target platform for CMake? For instance x86, x64, amd64.
I've tried set `TARGET_CPU=x64` but not sure does it works or not.

Comment: What is your method of "making sure it works"?

Comment: I use Travis CI. I see message: Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:    TARGET_CPU. That is why I have doubts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When calling the `cmake` command you can define a generator for instance Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 which results in the target platform **x64**

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -H%SOURCE_ROOT_DIR% -BC:\build\vs2015\x64\MyProject
```

If you like to build for **x86** on Windows with VS2015 - you would go this way:

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015" -H%SOURCE_ROOT_DIR% -BC:\build\vs2015\x64\MyProject
```

**ARM**:

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 ARM" -H%SOURCE_ROOT_DIR% -BC:\build\vs2015\x64\MyProject
```

Depending on your problem maybe [a CMake toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) can help you.

Answer (score 9):

To specify it in the `CMakeLists.txt` use:

```
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64)
```

and

```
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM win32)
```

before calling the `project()` command

Answer (score 8):

To specify 64 bit architecture for Visual Studio do:

```
cmake -A x64 .
```

Answer (score 2):

A little update for Cmake 3.17 and Visual Studio 2019.

In this case, even if you specify a generator with -G, you have to use the -A option with either Win32 or Win64.